# Entity framework getting around unsupported methods

Tags: sql, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

ADO.NET EF does not support things like Math.Pow and Math.Log so I was wondering how I can get around this.  I need to be able to use an ORDER BY on a calculated value using ADO.NET EF.

Comment: why do you need to Order By a power or Log function?

Comment: still not making much sense...

Comment: I need to be able to score each row in a database and sort it so I can the top N number of rows ordered by this score rather than grabbing every row and doing it client side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can using Entity SQL, but I wouldn't recommend it

```
using System.Data.EntityClient;

EntityConnection conn = new EntityConnection(myContext.Connection.ConnectionString);
conn.Open();
EntityCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandText = @"Select SqlServer.Power(t.MyValue, 2) From MyEntities.MyTable As t";
var result = cmd.ExecuteReader(System.Data.CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess);
result.Read();
var valuePower2 = result.GetValue(0);
conn.Close();
```

To do dynamic order by's and where clauses use [Dynamic Linq](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx)